# C# array/list into DataGridView Column

Tags: c#, arrays, list, datagridview

my Code looks like this:

```
public class A
    {
        public string N{ get; set; }

        public int E1 { get; set; }

        public int E2{ get; set; }

        public List<Genre> G{ get; set; }

        [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
        public string L { get; set; }
    }
```

and I have a BindingList that contains many of them. Now I want to display this list in a DataGridView, which works pretty good, except that the List inside the A's is NOT shown.

Binding the DataSource:

```
dgSeen.DataSource = Storage.seen;
```

the List G gets set after some time, and has the correct value(s).
So all what I want is, that there is a 4th DataGridView column that shows me the content of the List like "Action, Fatasy, SciFy" and so on.

I hope you understand what I need, and thanks in advance for every help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a computed property for this purpose.

```
public string GDisplay 
{
    get 
    {
        return String.Join(", ", G);
    }
}
```

Then use `GDisplay` in your grid to represent G. Obviously this is a read-only design. If you want to be able to modify the value of G via the grid, you'll have to implement a setter for `GDisplay`. For example:

```
    set 
    {
        G = value.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .Select(x => x.Trim())
                 .ToList();   
    }
```

Comment: thx, that worked perfectly :)
i dont need to edit it, so no need for that